# How to use multiple variables for AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I would like to use a yml variables file, rather than an ARM parameters file, so that I can use a single variable file for multiple bicep deployment tasks and to use the variables in other pipeline tasks without duplication, but am having trouble with the syntax. Below is what I have. It seems to not see it as valid syntax. I get the following error:
`There was an error while overriding 'tags' parameter because of 'SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input', make sure it follows JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)`

What is the correct syntax or is there a better way that meets the criteria?

```
# vars.yml contents
rsgName: "rsg1"
location: "westus"
tags: |
  {
  "tag1": "tagA",
  "tag2": "tagB"
  }

# deploy.yml contents
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: 'Subscription'
      azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ parameters.azureServiceConnection }}
      subscriptionId: ${{ variables.subId }}
      templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
      csmFile: ./template.bicep
      overrideParameters: >
        -rsgName ${{ variables.rsgName }}
        -location ${{ variables.location }}
        -tags ${{ variables.tags }}
      deploymentMode: 'Validation'

# template.bicep contents
param rsgName string
param location string

targetScope = 'subscription'

resource resourceGroup 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-04-01' = {
  name: rsgName
  location: location
  tags: tags
```

Comment: Your JSON is malformed. `"tag2": "tagB",` has an extra trailing comma.

Comment: Thank you. I have removed it in the example. It was not present in my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

As per the task [doc](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md), it supports multiple parameters overwrite on the task.

If you use classic UI editor of the task,  click `...` , it could be more clear.

[image]

The error should be caused by the incorrect format on the tag definition on your `vars.yml` .

1. Remove extra `,`  behind `"tag2": "tagB"` to fix the json format for a check.
2. Or you can try to use simple tag content for a check.

Comment: I have removed the comma from the example, which didn't exist in the original code. If I remove the tags entirely, I get `The 'location' property must be specified`

Comment: Thanks @Philosophene. To narrow down the issue, please try to export the value of `${{ variables.location }}`, does it have correct value? In addition, please try to replace real value for `location` on bicep content for a check, will the error disappear?

Comment: The variables show up in the pipeline. This issue is getting them to work in bicep.